# Having issues connecting to express backend with React

Tags: reactjs, express

Trying to set up a register form using react and then sending the form to my express backed to create the user. The request is getting to the back-end but none of the form data is there.
When i console.log the request body and params, only an empty object gets returned

Here is my react register code

```js
import React from 'react'

class Register extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        username: "",
        password: ""
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        this.setState({[name]:value})
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch("/api/register", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
        .then((result)=> result.json())
        .then((info) => { console.log(info); })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} placeholder="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} placeholder="username" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} placeholder="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <button>Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Register
```

Express code

```js
const express = require("express"),
      passport = require("passport"),
      User = require("../models/user");

const router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});


// /api before this
router.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        name: req.body.name
    });
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
            res.redirect("/user/" + user._id);
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now im getting a 400 bad request error and another error that says: register:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the url from the fetch action is not matching your express route

```
/api/register > /register
```

Try adding `/api` to the express route or remove from the fetch action
I also noticed your route is not returning anything.
You have to return something in the response object.

```
res.json(newUser);
```

```js
router.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        name: req.body.name
    });

    // some code

  return res.json(newUser);
});
```

Comment: If the route wasn't correct, the console.log wouldn't be fired server side.

Comment: Now it says: register:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0. Is it not being sent as JSON or what?

Comment: Only thing i changed was that i added res.json(user); at the end of the register post route

Comment: What does  User.register do? Does it call another service over http? It looks to me that it is asynchronous, so you have to return the json only after the register call is complete

Comment: Could you take a look at my newest question, its the updated code with more info

Comment: Could you foward the new question link @noahdubs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364193/error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-b-in-json-at-position-0